# Team Collaboration using Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: jupyter

Is there an alternative to JupyterHub that allows sharing of notebooks across team members. We need the following requirements:

Be able to run the server on a HPC. 
Multiple user login.
Version control with Git or similar service.
Sharing of notebooks between team members.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18734739/4993513 ?